# how to use same column multiple time in rdlc

Tags: c#, rdlc

in my rdlc Replot I have two column "Student Name" and "RESULT",
so when there are about 50 students,
it takes 3page reports, i mean 20 students record showing in one page,

I just want to reduce number of pages.

So is there any function in rdlc so, i can show 40 students side by side, means
use both column two times per page,

ex:

[image: Desired Out put]

Currenttly its showing like this:

[image]

note: I m doing this in c#.net

Answer (score 1):

I have used the RowNumber function with modulus to toggle alternations a lot in reports with good success. So for example, you could place 2 tables side by side and use a row group with a custom expression for each (I have not tested this particular case). Hope it helps.

```
=RowNumber("DataSet1") Mod 2 = 0
=RowNumber("DataSet1") Mod 2 = 1
```